# Python's fmin_cobyla "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm having a bit of trouble with `fmin_cobyla`. My constraint function is the problem, as it produces the error there. I'm getting the following error message:

```
File "C:/Users/daniel/Documents/Python Scripts/GST_physics\ML_GST.py", line 85, in ML_GST
   x_opt=scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla(objectiveFunction,parameters,ConstrainFunction)

File "C:\Users\daniel\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\cobyla.py", line 171, in fmin_cobyla **opts)

File "C:\Users\daniel\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\cobyla.py", line 246, in _minimize_cobyla
    dinfo=info)

File "C:\Users\daniel\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\cobyla.py", line 240, in calcfc con[k] = c['fun'](x, *c['args'])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Here is the code for the constraint function. I didn't post all the code because there's a lot of user defined functions that wouldn't make sense. Much of the code involves the `qutip` package for quantum computing work.

The problem occurs in this function. `G` is a list of matrices, `rho` and `E` are arrays, and `pauli_basis` is a list of `Qobjs`.

```
def ConstrainFunction(x):

    [G_chol,r,E]=ParamToGate(x,parameterSizes)

    G=[qptInv(np.transpose(np.conj(g))*g,op_basis) for g in G_chol]
    G=[np.transpose(np.conj(g))*g for g in G]
    c=[]

    ceq=np.zeros((len(pauli_basis),len(G)))

    for ii in range(len(G)):
        for rr in range(len(pauli_basis)):
            for mm in range(len(G)):
                for nn in range(len(G)):
                    ceq[rr,ii]=ceq[rr,ii]+G[ii][mm,nn]*(pauli_basis[mm]*pauli_basis[rr]*pauli_basis[nn]).tr()
            ceq[rr,ii]=ceq[rr,ii]-kroneckerDelta(0,rr)*(2**(num_qubits*2))

    ceq=np.matrix(ceq)
    ceq=np.array(mat2vec(ceq))
    lengthCEQ=len(ceq)
    rho=np.transpose(np.conj(r))*r
    traceerror=np.trace(rho)-1.0
    ceq=np.vstack([np.array(ceq),np.array([[traceerror.real]])])
    return ceq
x_opt=scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla(objectiveFunction,parameters,ConstrainFunction)
```

Comment: The docs say that the `cons` keyword takes a function or a sequence of functions: `Constraint functions; must all be >=0 (a single function if only 1 constraint). Each function takes the parameters x as its first argument.` - Are you sure that what you do is actually api conform? If I interpret your code correctly, you are returning a function with multidimensional output, judging from the doc string this may be not supported.